How unity redirect full path of packages folder?
This question is not specific to unity game engine itself, but there is a behaviour of unity application that, in the editor process, whenever we use any System.IO api such as Path.GetFullPath or File.Open with folder "Packages\AnyPackage", it seem it would redirect the non existing folder to the exist folder somewhere else
It's like it has symbolic link, but I can't find it
Or did the OS has some way other to inject path handling when using API relate to IO for the process? Or do we have a system to remap folder programmatically in the process?
edit: for @shingo
Suppose we create new Unity project and add package into the project, suppose it was named com.unity.mathematics
There will be folder {Project}\Packages created. With some json manifest but no com.unity.mathematics folder or any file at all
But the real package was created in another folder, {Project}\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.mathematics@1.2.6
In cmd terminal, using where command or dir command will not found anything relate to that folder because nothing except 2 json file exist in that folder
But in unity editor code I can write some function like this
[MenuItem("TT/TTTT")]
[InitializeOnLoadMethod]
public static void TTTT()
{
    var relativePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,"Packages","com.unity.mathematics");
    string path = Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);
    Debug.Log("1 - " + relativePath);
    Debug.Log("2 - " + path);
}

And it will output
1 - C:\<MyProjectFolder>\Packages\com.unity.mathematics
2 - C:\<MyProjectFolder>\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.mathematics@1.2.6

Which is expected behaviour, no problem at all
I just don't know what technique or mechanic to made this possible

Please show your code, and please explain in detail which folder does not exist, which folder does exist, and why you feel that the IO APIs seem to redirect non-existent folder to existing folder.

@shingo Is these detail I have added contain enough info?

Unity uses a customized GetFullPath method which will call the MonoIO.RemapPath method to remap the path, MonoIO is an internal class but you can try it with reflection. This method will call a C function which is internally registered with this function by Unity. I don't want to go deep, these info should be enough.

@shingo Thank you very much, would you like to made this an answer?
